# To add the content in to the database

Tags: android

how to solved that error how to get the array list Result sets of queries are returned in Cursor objects. There are some common methods that you will use with cursors

```
public class DBAdapter {
        Context c;
        CluecatalogOpenHelper helper;
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        int flag=0;

        public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
            super();
            this.c = ctx;
            helper=new CluecatalogOpenHelper(ctx);
        }
        public void openDB(){

            db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        public void closeDB(){
            db.close();
        }

        public void addRow(String name, byte[] data1) {

                openDB();
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("name", name); 
                values.put("object",data1);
                db.insert("topsearch", null, values);
                closeDB();        
        }


        public void deleteRow(String name)
        {
        try {
db.execSQL("delete from topsearch where name = (?)",new String[]{""+name});
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
                                }
        }

        public Cursor showData(){
        try{
         Cursor c = db.query("topsearch", new String[]{"name","object"}, null, null,null, null,null);
            return c;
            }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
            }}}
```

how to solved that error

Comment: Please, translate this question into English!!

Comment: A little hard to understand :/

Comment: What is the error that you're trying to overcome?

Comment: Really hard to figure out what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but if you're asking how do you pull out the results out of a Cursor object and into a List you would do it like this:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
Cursor c = db.query("topsearch", new String[]{"name","object"}, null, null,null, null,null);

while(c.moveToNext())
{
    //populate your return object from the cursor here
    //i'm just making this part up
    Obj obj = new Obj();

    obj.setName(c.getString(0));  //0 being the column index

    list.add(obj);
}

return list;
```